# RecyclerView in NestedScrollView recyclerView.scrollToPosition is 0

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-nestedscrollview

I have a 2 reusable methods to restore the position of an item in y RecyclerView when I return to the Fragment. It works for my other Fragments. But I have a Fragment with Flexible space with the image [scrolling-techniques-behavior](https://material.io/guidelines/patterns/scrolling-techniques.html#scrolling-techniques-behavior), having a RecyclerView in a NestedScrollView. I am unable to obtain the position and offset. I can obtain the position from the Adapter. But when I try to restore the position, nothing happens and it always shows the top item.

```
public static void storeRecyclerViewListPosition(Activity activity, final RecyclerView recyclerView, String identifier) {
        Log.i(TAG, "storeRecyclerViewListPosition: " + identifier);
        SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(activity);

        View firstChild = recyclerView.getChildAt(0);
        if (firstChild != null) {
            int firstVisiblePosition = recyclerView.getChildAdapterPosition(firstChild);
            int offset = firstChild.getTop();

            Log.d(TAG, "storeRecyclerViewListPosition: " + identifier + "_position: " + firstVisiblePosition);
            Log.d(TAG, "storeRecyclerViewListPosition: " + identifier + "_offset: " + offset);

            preferences.edit()
                    .putInt(identifier + "_position", firstVisiblePosition)
                    .putInt(identifier + "_offset", offset)
                    .apply();
        }
    }


public static void restoreRecyclerViewListPosition(Activity activity, final RecyclerView recyclerView, final String identifier) {
        Log.i(TAG, "restoreRecyclerViewListPosition: " + identifier);

        final SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(activity);
        Log.d(TAG, "storeRecyclerViewListPosition: " + identifier + "_position: " + preferences.getInt(identifier + "_position", 0));
        Log.d(TAG, "storeRecyclerViewListPosition: " + identifier + "_offset: " + preferences.getInt(identifier + "_offset", 0));

        recyclerView.scrollToPosition(preferences.getInt(identifier + "_position", 0));
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                recyclerView.scrollBy(0, - preferences.getInt(identifier + "_offset", 0));
            }
        }, 500);
    }
```

Comment: @wesely, fixed it

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is basically this:

```
int firstVisiblePosition = recyclerView.getChildAdapterPosition(recyclerView.getChildAt(0));
```

As the title suggests, this is the same as doing this:

```
int firstVisiblePosition = 0;
```

Instead you should be doing this:

```
int firstVisiblePosition = ((LinearLayoutManager) recyclerView.getLayoutManager()).findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition();
```

Works with `GridLayoutManager`, too.

I adopted your methods accordingly and edited them somewhat. This works for me:

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    storeRecyclerViewListPosition();
    super.onPause();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    restoreRecyclerViewListPosition();
    super.onResume();
}

public void storeRecyclerViewListPosition() {
    SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    int firstVisiblePosition = ((LinearLayoutManager) recyclerView.getLayoutManager()).findFirstVisibleItemPosition();
    preferences.edit().putInt("position", firstVisiblePosition).apply();
}


public void restoreRecyclerViewListPosition() {
    final SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    recyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(preferences.getInt("position", 0));
}
```

Comment: Not working. firstVisiblePosition is still 0. I need a solution to scroll it to the position as layoutManager.smoothScrollToPosition(recyclerView, new RecyclerView.State(), preferences.getInt(TAG + "_position", 0)); is not restoring the position even when the value is not 0.

Comment: @twelvester Please see my edited post with working code.

Comment: restoreRecyclerViewListPosition () is not working. Are you using a CoordinatorLayout with AppBarLayout > CollapsingToolbarLayout and NestedScrollView > LinearLayout > RecyclerView? This fragment is the only one with issue. Other fragments, CoordinatorLayout with AppBarLayout and RecyclerView (without CollapsingToolbarLayout and NestedScrollView) is working even with my old code.

Comment: I cannot add my layout.xml as the editor is says its not formatted properly. Is there another way to share my layout.xml file?